# How do I bypass the authentication to set another password?

Tags: 12.04

I have an administrative accout with no password yet it still asks for authentication and  it won't except my old password or "user". What should I do?

Comment: I can't enter recovery mode

Comment: @EmontiLewis - there are multiple answers to that question, so try another one, e.g [this one](http://askubuntu.com/a/435347/178596). Recovery mode is the easiest way, try looking under 'Advancded options' or something